# NumberFormatException in Content Service

Tags: web8.5, content-delivery, metadata, query, content-service

We have a Java website running on the latest hotfix version of CIL (8.5.0-16778).  The CMS we are using is SDL Web 8.5 with the micro-service CD environment.  Our site makes multiple calls to the content service to obtain DCPs.  These calls are generated with various metadata criteria based on the productCodes that we are using to uniquely identify content in the CMS (the productCodes are stored as metadata on components in the CMS).  While running our load tests through hundreds of different queries for productCodes, we obtain the following error logs on the content service:

```
2019-12-13 14:59:12,809 ERROR ODataWriteProcessorImpl - Unexpected Exception when persisting or deleting an entity.
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ".507508053E8E8"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2056)
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:123)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:549)
    at java.text.DigitList.getDouble(DigitList.java:180)
    at java.text.DecimalFormat.parse(DecimalFormat.java:2067)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.subParse(SimpleDateFormat.java:1880)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.parse(SimpleDateFormat.java:1525)
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:375)
    at com.sdl.web.api.broker.TypeConverterUtil.handleObjectType(TypeConverterUtil.java:27)
    at com.sdl.web.api.broker.querying.criteria.strategies.CustomMetaValueStrategy.getWhere(CustomMetaValueStrategy.java:38)
    at com.sdl.web.api.broker.querying.criteria.DecoratedCriteria.getWhere(DecoratedCriteria.java:109)
    at com.sdl.web.api.broker.querying.criteria.strategies.OperatorStrategy.getWhere(OperatorStrategy.java:87)
    at com.sdl.web.api.broker.querying.criteria.DecoratedCriteria.getWhere(DecoratedCriteria.java:109)
    at com.sdl.web.api.broker.querying.criteria.DecoratedCriteria.getWhere(DecoratedCriteria.java:118)
    at com.sdl.web.api.broker.querying.criteria.strategies.OperatorStrategy.getWhere(OperatorStrategy.java:82)
    at com.sdl.web.api.broker.querying.criteria.DecoratedCriteria.getWhere(DecoratedCriteria.java:109)
    at com.sdl.web.api.broker.querying.criteria.DecoratedCriteria.getWhere(DecoratedCriteria.java:118)
    at com.sdl.web.api.broker.querying.generators.JPQLQueryGenerationUtil.generateQuery(JPQLQueryGenerationUtil.java:60)
    at com.sdl.web.content.odata.query.service.QueryServiceImpl.generateQuery(QueryServiceImpl.java:76)
    at com.sdl.web.content.odata.query.service.QueryServiceImpl.executeQuery(QueryServiceImpl.java:48)
    at com.sdl.web.content.odata.util.QueryExecutionUtil.getQueryResult(QueryExecutionUtil.java:52)
    at com.sdl.web.content.odata.action.ExecuteQueryAction.doContentServiceOperation(ExecuteQueryAction.java:102)
    at com.sdl.web.content.odata.action.ExecuteQueryAction.doContentServiceOperation(ExecuteQueryAction.java:47)
    at com.sdl.web.content.odata.ContentServiceOperation.doOperation(ContentServiceOperation.java:36)
    at com.sdl.odata.processor.write.ActionPostMethodHandler.handleWrite(ActionPostMethodHandler.java:54)
    at com.sdl.odata.processor.ODataWriteProcessorImpl.write(ODataWriteProcessorImpl.java:57)
    at com.sdl.odata.service.actor.ODataWriteProcessorActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(ODataWriteProcessorActor.scala:33)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:480)
    at com.sdl.odata.service.actor.ODataWriteProcessorActor.aroundReceive(ODataWriteProcessorActor.scala:28)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:526)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:495)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:224)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1160)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:795)
2019-12-13 14:59:12,810 DEBUG ODataMessageRouter - Sending error message for exception:
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ".507508053E8E8"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2056)
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:123)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:549)
    at java.text.DigitList.getDouble(DigitList.java:180)
    at java.text.DecimalFormat.parse(DecimalFormat.java:2067)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.subParse(SimpleDateFormat.java:1880)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.parse(SimpleDateFormat.java:1525)
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:375)
    at com.sdl.web.api.broker.TypeConverterUtil.handleObjectType(TypeConverterUtil.java:27)
    at com.sdl.web.api.broker.querying.criteria.strategies.CustomMetaValueStrategy.getWhere(CustomMetaValueStrategy.java:38)
    at com.sdl.web.api.broker.querying.criteria.DecoratedCriteria.getWhere(DecoratedCriteria.java:109)
    at com.sdl.web.api.broker.querying.criteria.strategies.OperatorStrategy.getWhere(OperatorStrategy.java:87)
    at com.sdl.web.api.broker.querying.criteria.DecoratedCriteria.getWhere(DecoratedCriteria.java:109)
    at com.sdl.web.api.broker.querying.criteria.DecoratedCriteria.getWhere(DecoratedCriteria.java:118)
    at com.sdl.web.api.broker.querying.criteria.strategies.OperatorStrategy.getWhere(OperatorStrategy.java:82)
    at com.sdl.web.api.broker.querying.criteria.DecoratedCriteria.getWhere(DecoratedCriteria.java:109)
    at com.sdl.web.api.broker.querying.criteria.DecoratedCriteria.getWhere(DecoratedCriteria.java:118)
    at com.sdl.web.api.broker.querying.generators.JPQLQueryGenerationUtil.generateQuery(JPQLQueryGenerationUtil.java:60)
    at com.sdl.web.content.odata.query.service.QueryServiceImpl.generateQuery(QueryServiceImpl.java:76)
    at com.sdl.web.content.odata.query.service.QueryServiceImpl.executeQuery(QueryServiceImpl.java:48)
    at com.sdl.web.content.odata.util.QueryExecutionUtil.getQueryResult(QueryExecutionUtil.java:52)
    at com.sdl.web.content.odata.action.ExecuteQueryAction.doContentServiceOperation(ExecuteQueryAction.java:102)
    at com.sdl.web.content.odata.action.ExecuteQueryAction.doContentServiceOperation(ExecuteQueryAction.java:47)
    at com.sdl.web.content.odata.ContentServiceOperation.doOperation(ContentServiceOperation.java:36)
    at com.sdl.odata.processor.write.ActionPostMethodHandler.handleWrite(ActionPostMethodHandler.java:54)
    at com.sdl.odata.processor.ODataWriteProcessorImpl.write(ODataWriteProcessorImpl.java:57)
    at com.sdl.odata.service.actor.ODataWriteProcessorActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(ODataWriteProcessorActor.scala:33)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:480)
    at com.sdl.odata.service.actor.ODataWriteProcessorActor.aroundReceive(ODataWriteProcessorActor.scala:28)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:526)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:495)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:224)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1160)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:795)
2019-12-13 14:59:12,810 ERROR ODataRendererActor - Unexpected exception during response rendering - java.lang.NumberFormatException: 'For input string: ".507508053E8E8"'
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ".507508053E8E8"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2056)
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:123)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:549)
    at java.text.DigitList.getDouble(DigitList.java:180)
    at java.text.DecimalFormat.parse(DecimalFormat.java:2067)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.subParse(SimpleDateFormat.java:1880)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.parse(SimpleDateFormat.java:1525)
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:375)
    at com.sdl.web.api.broker.TypeConverterUtil.handleObjectType(TypeConverterUtil.java:27)
    at com.sdl.web.api.broker.querying.criteria.strategies.CustomMetaValueStrategy.getWhere(CustomMetaValueStrategy.java:38)
    at com.sdl.web.api.broker.querying.criteria.DecoratedCriteria.getWhere(DecoratedCriteria.java:109)
    at com.sdl.web.api.broker.querying.criteria.strategies.OperatorStrategy.getWhere(OperatorStrategy.java:87)
    at com.sdl.web.api.broker.querying.criteria.DecoratedCriteria.getWhere(DecoratedCriteria.java:109)
    at com.sdl.web.api.broker.querying.criteria.DecoratedCriteria.getWhere(DecoratedCriteria.java:118)
    at com.sdl.web.api.broker.querying.criteria.strategies.OperatorStrategy.getWhere(OperatorStrategy.java:82)
    at com.sdl.web.api.broker.querying.criteria.DecoratedCriteria.getWhere(DecoratedCriteria.java:109)
    at com.sdl.web.api.broker.querying.criteria.DecoratedCriteria.getWhere(DecoratedCriteria.java:118)
    at com.sdl.web.api.broker.querying.generators.JPQLQueryGenerationUtil.generateQuery(JPQLQueryGenerationUtil.java:60)
    at com.sdl.web.content.odata.query.service.QueryServiceImpl.generateQuery(QueryServiceImpl.java:76)
    at com.sdl.web.content.odata.query.service.QueryServiceImpl.executeQuery(QueryServiceImpl.java:48)
    at com.sdl.web.content.odata.util.QueryExecutionUtil.getQueryResult(QueryExecutionUtil.java:52)
    at com.sdl.web.content.odata.action.ExecuteQueryAction.doContentServiceOperation(ExecuteQueryAction.java:102)
    at com.sdl.web.content.odata.action.ExecuteQueryAction.doContentServiceOperation(ExecuteQueryAction.java:47)
    at com.sdl.web.content.odata.ContentServiceOperation.doOperation(ContentServiceOperation.java:36)
    at com.sdl.odata.processor.write.ActionPostMethodHandler.handleWrite(ActionPostMethodHandler.java:54)
    at com.sdl.odata.processor.ODataWriteProcessorImpl.write(ODataWriteProcessorImpl.java:57)
    at com.sdl.odata.service.actor.ODataWriteProcessorActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(ODataWriteProcessorActor.scala:33)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:480)
    at com.sdl.odata.service.actor.ODataWriteProcessorActor.aroundReceive(ODataWriteProcessorActor.scala:28)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:526)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:495)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:224)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1160)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:795)
```

Any idea what might be causing this?

Additional relevant info:

- We have the ADF enabled with lots of triggers and claims.
- 99% of the load tests work, only a few fail with similar messages (The exact string it fails on differs.)

Comment: Worth enable in the content service tomcat access logs to see the request URLs and then try to reproduce to check the logs times and request times to analyze to drill down. for me looks like something invalid data something getting passed.

Comment: We've submitted a support ticket for it, SDL has confirmed it as a bug on their end.  I'll post an answer once the hotfix is out.

Comment: Any news on this hotfix? I'm having the same problem. I've checked it's not an schema issue.

Comment: @InmaculadaPalacios I just posted the answer below with the hotfix version.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this type of problem before. In our case the problem was due to schema changes.

When a schema metadata field data type has been changed you must

- update all components using the schema
- republish items using the schema

Check the metadata field type in the broker database to verify that all of the published metadata is the correct type.

Answer (score 1):

SDL Provided a hotfix to us to resolve this issue.  The hotfix was:
CD_8.5.0.17761
and we confirmed that it resolved our issue.